# Setting UIScrollView content offset in a UITableViewCell doesn't work in non-reused dequeued cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` placed inside my `UITableViewCell` subclass and I want to set content x-offset of the `UIScrollView` to 320 before the `UITableView` displays it.

So no problem, I call `setContentOffset` on my `UIScrollView` inside my `configureCell:withIndexPath:` method and call the latter in my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.  This is how it looks:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"myCellNib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  [_tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  myCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
  return cell;
}


- (void)configureCell:(myCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [cell.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0)];
}
```

So far so good, except now the first batch of loaded cells are not getting the desired result (all subviews and their properties are being set correctly, except for the content offset), but if I scroll down the `UITableView` the newly loaded (reused) cells are fine and I'm not sure what's really going on.  HALP!

NOTE: I checked that my cell subviews (`UIScrollView`) are not nil when I'm calling `setContentOffset` on them and I get the right result from `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(offset));`

NOTE: The solution I am implementing for this is to check for the `UIScrollView` `contentSize` property and to manually set it if it is equal to `CGSizeZero`, which is what'll happen when initializing non-reused cells from a registered NIB.

```
if (CGSizeEqualToSize(cell.scrollView.contentSize, CGSizeZero)) {
  [cell.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3, 150)];  
}
```

Comment: it should be something about the cells created by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` when there is no reusable cell, but I can't figure it out even after reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Comment: can you post your scrollview creation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is you are trying to set the content offset too early in the views life cycle. What you need to do is try overwriting `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Maybe something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    //write some loop here to cycle through all the index paths and then:
    myCell *cell = (myCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];



}
```

Write a loop to iterate though all the indexes and get the cells. Then call the configure cell method. Also make sure you keep that code for setting the offset in the prepareCellForReuse.  This will ensure it is not done until the views are setup and it should fix your problem. This is why your reused cells are fine, because the views are already setup. Try this.

Comment: I'm using IB.  I registered the nib file with my `UITableView` in my code.  In that way, `UITableViewCell`'s are initialized using `initWithCoder:` instead of `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

Comment: yup that's right, try moving the code to initWithCoder and prepareForReuse

Comment: I just tried and it didn't make a difference as one might expect. `prepareForReuse` is only called on the reused cells.  they're not the ones I have problem with.

Comment: can you try putting [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO]; in the view controller or table view controller you are using. in the viewDidLoad

Comment: seems you're not the only one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720102/uiscrollview-inside-uitableviewcell-doesnt-always-obey-setcontentoffsetanimate

Comment: if the guy needed a delay it means he must be trying to set the offset BEFORE adding the content to the scrollview. Check your code and make sure the content is added and everything is setup properly before setting the offset. This would explain why your reused cells are fine because the content has been added properly before setting the offset...

Comment: You're right.  It boiled down to the `contentSize` property not being set at the point I'm setting `contentOffset` since I am using a NIB with autolayout and layout constraints.

Comment: I edited my answer, you're setting the offset too early in the view life cycle. Try something like above. I'm excited. It's going to work.